# Parameter 0 of method init in com.ayman.image.Main required a bean of type 'com.ayman.image.storage.StorageService' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javabeans

I have a Spring app. I am using Eclipse IDE on Windows.

When initiating my Spring app I am instantiating my app with StorageService Interface.

```
package com.ayman.image;
import org.springframework.boot.*;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;


import com.ayman.image.storage.StorageService;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.ayman.image.storage") //added this line by myself
public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner init(StorageService storageService) {
        return (args) -> {
            storageService.deleteAll();
            storageService.init();
        };
    }
}
```

When running this Spring App I am getting the error

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method init in com.mastercard.ayman.image.Main required a 
bean of type 'com.mastercard.ayman.image.storage.StorageService' that could 
not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 
'com.ayman.image.storage.StorageService' in your configuration.
```

I have defined my Bean using component scan. Is this the wrong approach?

Comment: How is `StorageService` defined?

Answer (score 0):

The problem may come from StorageService not being a Spring bean. If the bean is not defined with pertinent spring annotations, you should initialize it in the same way as you did with CommandLineRunner.

Answer (score 0):

change  it like that it works for me

```
public class SpringBootSecurityJwtApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
@Resource
FilesStorageService storageService;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SpringBootSecurityJwtApplication.class, args);
    System.out.println("version: " + SpringBootVersion.getVersion());
}
@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
  storageService.deleteAll();
   storageService.init();
}
```